# Sass: compile CSS by selectors with color property

Tags: sass

Is it possible in SASS to generate a CSS file, where only selectors with a color property are stored?

e.g. 
This SASS file

```
class-1 {  
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 1rem 1rem;
  color: #000;
}

class-2 {  
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 1rem 1rem;
}

class-3 {  
  display: flex;
  color: #000;
}
```

should be outputted as:

```
class-1 {  
  color: #000;
}

class-3 {  
  color: #000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible with Sass itself, but you can filter out unwanted properties by using [PostCSS](https://postcss.org/).

I'm not aware about any plugin that does exactly this, but it should not be hard to write one by yourself. You can refer [postcss-select](https://github.com/johno/postcss-select) plugin as a starting point for your implementation as it filters out CSS based on selectors.